# PHP code for Block visibility by Vocabulary ID

Tags: 7, blocks

I need to show a block for terms of a certain vocabulery. Drupal.org has this snippit for Drupal 6, but I cant find anything for Drupal 7.

http://drupal.org/node/69076

Im looking at PHP in the block visibility settings as Im assuming its the best way, but id be happy with any other solution. Thanks

Comment: Ive found this question i posted a while ago for D6 but I need a D7 solution and I dont want to install the context module.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605911/drupal-show-block-on-all-term-pages-for-one-vocabulary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this on the term pages you should be able to use [this code from Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/706336#comment-4327606). Just replace the function call taxonomy_get_term with taxonomy_term_load.

The code is copied below:

```
 <?php
  $desired_vocab = 1; // put here the vocabulary ID you're interested in

  if ( ((arg(0) == 'taxonomy')
    && (arg(1) == 'term')
    && is_numeric(arg(2))
    && ($term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2)))
    && ($term->vid == $desired_vocab )) ) {
      return TRUE;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to avoid placing PHP in the database. I suggest you use the module [Block Visibility by Term](https://drupal.org/project/block_term).